# sql compact 3.5 sp2 download and silent install

Tags: sql-server-ce, inno-setup

I don't think I'll get an answer to this one, because it's so obscure, but what the heck. I'm trying to INNO setup to install SQL COMPACT as part of the install process.

I've got the correct script, which downloads the file SSCERuntime-ENU. But it looks like the download has changed because INNO SETUP always says it's not a valid installer. So I unpacked it and there's 2x MSI's for X86 and X64. I want my application to run on both X86 and X64, so I'll need to run both install packages.

Anyway, has anyone come across this before? Is there's an easy way to tell the SSCERuntime to install one or both versions? I can't seem to find a command line parameter to do that since the runtime appears to be self extracting archive which drops both those MSI packages...

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so numerous frustrating hours later. I gave up trying to get the installer to run and it appears I can just include the SQL CE DLL's directly into the bin directory and it doesn't need to be installed. I've tried this under Win7x86 and WinVistax86. But I'm just trying it under Win7x64 to make sure it picks up the correct version. According to everything I've read so long as the app is compiled to run under x86 it shouldn't need the x64 SQL CE files...

Comment: That is correct, but you can also include the sqlcexx.dll files in 2 folders for each platfrom, x86 and AMD64

Comment: Which DLL you are including?

Answer (score 1):

You need to extraxt files from e SSCERuntime-ENU.exe and then host SSCERuntime_x64-ENU.msi and SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.msi by yourself.

I've modified [Modular InnoSetup Dependecy Installer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20868/NET-Framework-1-1-2-0-3-5-Installer-for-InnoSetup)  to install Sql Compact DB

File: scripts/products/sqlcompact35sp2.iss

```
[CustomMessages]
sqlcompact35sp2_title=SQL Server Compact 3.5 Service Pack 2
sqlcompact35sp2_titlex64=SQL Server Compact 3.5 Service Pack 2  x64

en.sqlcompact35sp2_size=3.0 MB
de.sqlcompact35sp2_size=3.0 MB
en.sqlcompact35sp2_sizex64=3.5 MB
de.sqlcompact35sp2_sizex64=3.5 MB


[Code]
const
    sqlcompact35sp2_url = 'http://pliki.naturalmedia.pl/prerequisites/SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.msi';
  sqlcompact35sp2_urlx64 = 'http://pliki.naturalmedia.pl/prerequisites/SSCERuntime_x64-ENU.msi';

procedure sqlcompact35sp2();
begin
    if (not IsWin64 and
  not RegKeyExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\ENU')) then

        AddProduct('SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.msi',
            '/qb',
            CustomMessage('sqlcompact35sp2_title'),
            CustomMessage('sqlcompact35sp2_size'),
            sqlcompact35sp2_url,
            false, false);

 if (IsWin64
    and 
    (
       not RegKeyExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\ENU')
      and  not RegKeyExists(HKLM, 'Wow6432Node\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\ENU')
     )) then
    begin
            AddProduct('SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.msi',
            '/qb',
            CustomMessage('sqlcompact35sp2_title'),
            CustomMessage('sqlcompact35sp2_size'),
            sqlcompact35sp2_url,
            false, false);
            AddProduct('SSCERuntime_x64-ENU.msi',
            '/qb',
            CustomMessage('sqlcompact35sp2_titlex64'),
            CustomMessage('sqlcompact35sp2_sizex64'),
            sqlcompact35sp2_urlx64,
            false, false);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a 32-bit application you will only need to run the SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.msi installation package (even on x64 Windows as it will be running in the x86 emulator). However, if you need native 64-bit support, you can run the x64 package instead. They are just standard MSI files, so you apply the standard Windows Installer switches to msiexec.exe. Run `msiexec.exe /?` to obtain the full list of switches. Here is how to include the installer in your Inno Setup package, check for an existing installation and, if required, run the installer silently:

```
[Files]
Source: "Source Files\SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.msi"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Permissions: everyone-full; Flags: deleteafterinstall

[Run]
Filename: "{sys}\msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{tmp}\SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.msi"" /quiet /norestart"; StatusMsg: "Installing Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2..."; Flags: runhidden; Check: not IsMSSQL35Installed

[Code]
//Check if Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 is installed
function IsMSSQL35Installed(): Boolean;
var
  strVersion: String;
  strServicePack: String;
begin
  RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\ENU', 'DesktopRuntimeVersion', strVersion)
  RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\ENU', 'DesktopRuntimeServicePackLevel', strServicePack)
  if strVersion = '3.5.8080.0' and strServicePack = '2' then
    Result := True;
end;
```